# Open Dialog with textarea after Click

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, modal-dialog, textarea

I'm creating a Java Spring Web App and in it there is a form to be filled out by the user. In the form I have a textarea input type as one of the fields. In viewing the form, I only want the textarea to show roughly 50 characters and then end with '...' or something. However, the field itself can contain up to 250 characters. So, what I want to happen is that if the user clicks on the field, then the entire textarea opens up in a separate dialog so that the user can see potentially all of the characters that may be cut off in the normal field view. I don't have much to start with, but for the JavaScript I'll just give a base of:

```
    document.getElementById('hwDescription').onclick = function () {
        ...
    }
```

And the HTML element is:

```
<form:input id="hwDescription" type="text" class="form-control" path="hwDescription"
                    name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" />
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I sets minimum size of 10 see preview this it maybe works for you.

```js
document.getElementById('hwDescription').onclick = function () {
    
    this.classList.add("large");
        
    this.onkeypress = this.onkeydown = function() {
        this.size = ( this.value.length > 10 ) ? this.value.length : 10;
    };


}
```

```css
.large { 
   border: 1px solid #0d0;
}
```

```html
<input id="hwDescription" type="text" class="form-control short" path="hwDescription" name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" />
```

Comment: Sorry this wasn't what I was looking for. I was looking more for the textarea to be expanded in a separate dialog.